# Subclauses in formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

Quite often I end up including the same calculation in a formula twice, like this:

```
=if(iserror(vlookup("lookup",SheetX!A2:X350,5,false)),"",vlookup("lookup",SheetX!A2:X350,5,false))
```

I'd like to remove the duplication **without cluttering my sheet with endless hidden columns**. Is there some way to embed a subclause in a formula? Something like this?

```
=if(iserror(myLookup),"",myLookup)
where
myLookup = vlookup("lookup",SheetX!A2:X350,5,false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A match is going to be found for `lookup` or it is not going to be found so two vlookups are not necessary. In general what you seek is not possible, though where you want a response to be the result of one ‘clause’ or a different responses where that ‘clause’ returns an error there is the option of the `iferror` function. So your formula might be rewritten, and shortened:

```
=iferror(vlookup(A1,SheetX!A2:X350,5,0),"")
```